# easyPHP pages not displaying after running one of my pages through the command prompt

Tags: php, apache, easyphp

I've been running easyPHP on my machine for a while. After I ran one of my php-scripts through the command prompt I can't run any pages through easyPHP anymore. The dashboard is visible however, and everything seems to be running properly.
The command prompt runs a different version of PHP.

The error log says "Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?". So I wonder if running a script through the command prompt caused this?
Maybe it's a matter of ports clashing? But I tried changing which port easyPHP uses and it didn't work.

**php -v in the command prompt returns:**
PHP 7.1.3 (cli) (built: Mar 14 2017 23:46:26) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x86 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

**The error log for easyPHP says:**

> [Sun Jan 10 12:28:15.637348 2021] [core:warn] [pid 3520:tid 708] AH00098: pid file C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-binaries/httpserver/apache2425vc11x86x200825122144/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

> PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php5630vc11x86x200825122144\php.ini on line 886 in Unknown on line 0

> [Sun Jan 10 12:28:15.699813 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3520:tid 708] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations

> [Sun Jan 10 12:28:15.699813 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3520:tid 708] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Dec 20 2016 13:02:04

> [Sun Jan 10 12:28:15.699813 2021] [core:notice] [pid 3520:tid 708] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2425vc11x86x200825122144\bin\eds-httpserver.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-binaries/httpserver/apache2425vc11x86x200825122144'

> [Sun Jan 10 12:28:15.715435 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3520:tid 708] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 18140
> PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php5630vc11x86x200825122144\php.ini on line 886 in Unknown on line 0

> [Sun Jan 10 12:28:17.408723 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 18140:tid 648] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

Comment: What did the script do that you ran using the CLI?

Comment: And if you could upgrade your PHP to a current version most of these would probably disappear

Comment: The script did nothing out of the ordinary. I tried upgrading my php and the page still won't display. The error I get in Firefox is "Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1."